# Prove that any set of non-overlapping real intervals is countable

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a set of non-overlapping intervals of positive length (*"noipl"*).  Prove that $S$ is countable.

My proof is below.  Can you verify, critique, or improve it?

Assume $S$ consists only of noipls of finite length.  For any finite interval $(a,b), (a,b], [a,b],$ or $[a,b)$, define its *left-milestone* as $\lfloor a \rfloor$.  For each $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, let $S_n$ be the subset of $S$ whose elements have left-milestone $n$.  $S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} S_n$.  For any $S_n$, for any $l$ in $\mathbb{Z}^+$, let $S_{nl}$ be the subset of $S_n$ whose elements have length $\geq 1/l$.  The cardinality of each $S_{nl}$ is clearly finite, and $S_n = \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{Z}^+}S_{nl}$.  Since the union of a countable collection of finite sets is countable, $S_n$ is countable, and since the union of a countable collection of countable sets is countable, $S$ is countable.

As any set of noipls can include at most 2 noipls of infinite length, the proof is not changed if $S$ were to include noipls of infinite length as well.

Comment: There's a much easier proof of this: since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, each interval contains a rational and using that as the 'designation' of the interval, what is required follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data Interesting.  Your approach relies on the Axiom of Choice, correct?

Comment: Yes, forming the countable set of designating rationals requires choice.

Comment: No, you don't need the axiom of choice. The set of rational numbers is countable, so fix an enumeration of it. Then, for each of your intervals, designate its first rational member --- first in the fixed enumeration.

Comment: However, the Axiom of Choice **is** needed to prove that the union of a countable collection of finite sets is countable.